# Computer extremely slow after not using for 3 months

Tags: desktop-computer

I have a windows 10 desktop i built myself a year ago. It has 16 GB ram, intel i7 processor, and G970 radeon graphics card. The computer was extremely fast, able to run games on highest settings such as CS:GO at 200fps.

Over the summer I put it away for 3 months and I just booted it up again. Its extremely slow, even tasks such as scrolling a webpage or moving the mouse in circles has lags and strange delays. Now CS:GO runs at 20 FPS on a local server.

What would be the cause of this? Viruses, or does this happen to computers that haven't been used in a while? I have avast Antivirus and it says I am clean. I checked CPU and RAM usage and they are very low at around 10-20% however my computer is displaying massive signs of lag.

I tried reformatting my computer, and while it seems to have slightly better performance, the problem is still there.

In this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd0VE.jpg) after I reformatted, CS:GO is getting 14 FPS, but my Computer is only using 10% CPU and 28% RAM. Why is this?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: could it be installing a gazillion windows updates?

Comment: You noticed that your disk usage is consistently high.  Maybe the hard disk got damaged over time? Try running a disk check (`chkdsk C:`)

Comment: By reformatting do you mean drive defragmentation or something else?

Comment: reformatting as in erasing all the contents on the drive.

Comment: I ran chkdisk C: and here are the [results](http://pastebin.com/96Z9Ywqq).
I'm not sure how to read the results, but it seems there was an error the first time I ran the command. But when I ran it the second time it dissapeared?


My C: drive is a SSD if that makes a difference.

Answer (score -1):

1. Memory errors. Could be a RAM problem.  Run some memory tests offline (from boot) and see if you can find any errors.

> http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/

Has some great programs you can boot from a CD or a USB drive and run a bunch of different tests.

2. Video card driver.  This is much more likely the culprit.  You may have to downgrade your Nvidia or Radeon driver. Sometimes Windows updates can conflict with video card drivers and cause poor communication. This is the thing I would play around with the most. I don't know what a G970 is, but Radeon has a 6970 card and there are people that seem to have found issues with them soved by using the right video card driver

> https://www.google.com/search?q=radeon+driver+problems+with+g970&oq=radeon+driver+problems+with+g970&aqs=chrome..69i57.6178j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=radeon+driver+problems+with+6970

2.(5) Windows hotfix took over your video card driver.  If you hit Windows Key + R then type.

> compmgmt.msc

Click on Device manager and then open +display adapters.  Then right click your video card and see what driver version it is using. Compare it to the one on Radeon's website.

---

Found this at : http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-2813275/disk-usage-100.html

3. Disable- a.WSearch, b.superfetch and c.BIT. Then adjust the pagefile settings.

> go to control panel/system and security/system/advanced system
>       settings under performance click settings, advanced tab click
>       change, set min to 1024 x your ram to convert to MB and set max to 2
>       x the min. click set, OK and apply. requires a restart.

So if you have 16Gb RAM then 16 x 1024=16384 mb for the min and then double that 32768 mb for the max.

You might want to run msconfig and remove all your startup option check boxes as well.

Comment: I don't think the video card has any problem. I tried running a GPU benchmarking tool and it performed well. I will try running some memory tests

Comment: I noticed that disk usage is very high, almost 100%. Perhaps that is the reason behind the fps loss? How would that be fixed

Comment: High disk usage is definitely the cause, but you need to give us more info. What process is taking up high disk in Task Manager?

Comment: I updated my answer- Check out option 3